# Monte-Carlo Simulation for the sum of die

Tags: julia, montecarlo

I am very new to programming so I apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge.

I want to find the probability of obtaining the sum k when throwing m die. I am not looking for a direct answer, I just want to ask if I am on the right track and what I can improve.

I begin with a function that calculates the sum of an array of m die:

```
function dicesum(m)
j = rand((1:6), m)
sum(j)
end
```

Now I am trying specific values to see if I can find a pattern (but without much luck). I have tried m = 2 (two die). What I am trying to do is to write a function which checks whether the sum of the two die is k and if it is, it calculates the probability. My attempt is very naive but I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction:

```
m = 2
x, y = rand(1:6), rand(1:6)
z = x+y
if z == dicesum(m)
Probability = ??/6^m
```

I want to somehow find the number of 'elements' in dicesum(2) in order to calculate the probability. For example, consider the case when dicesum(2) = 8. With two die, the possible outcomes are (2,6),(6,2), (5,3), (3,5), (4,4), (4,4). The probability being (2/36)*3.

I understand that the general case is far more complicated but I just want an idea of how to being this problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use simulation to approximate the probability of obtaining a sum of k when roll m dice. What I recommend is creating a function that will take k and m as arguments and repeat the simulation a large number of times. The following might help you get started:

```
function Simulate(m,k,Nsim=10^4)
    #Initialize the counter
    cnt=0 
    #Repeat the experiment Nsim times
    for sim in 1:Nsim
        #Simulate roll of m dice
        s = sum(rand(1:6,m))
        #Increment counter if sum matches k
        if s == k 
            cnt += 1
        end
    end
    #Return the estimated probability
    return cnt/Nsim
end

prob = Simulate(3,4)
```

The estimate is approximately .0131.

Comment: Wow that's brilliant! I will have to read it a couple more times to understand it fully but I think I see what you are trying to do. Just one question: I have seen several examples of Monte Carlo simulations where `cnt = 0` or `count = 0` is used. But I don't quite understand why it is used here. Aren't we simply looping over all `sim in 1:Nsim`?

Comment: Ignore the comment above, I understand what you did. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform your simulation in a vectorized style as shown below. Its less efficient in terms of memory allocation because it creates a vector s of length Nsim, whereas the loop code uses a single integer to count, cnt. Sometimes unnecessary memory allocation can cause performance issues. In this case, it turns out that the vectorized code is about twice as fast. Usually, loops are a bit faster. Someone more familiar with the internals of Julia might be able to offer an explanation.

```
function Simulate1(m,k,Nsim=10^4)
    #Simulate roll of m dice Nsim times
    s = sum(rand(1:6,Nsim,m),2)
    #Relative frequency of matches
    prob = mean(s .== k)
    return prob
end
```

Comment: The reason is that the first solution allocates a small array 10^4 times, which is expensive. You allocate a big array once and then aggregate it. The original solution would be faster if it would calculate `s` using the following code `s = 0; for i in 1:m s += rand(1:6) end` as this avoids allocation.  You can check all this using `@benchmark` macro. You can yet improve the speed of the simulation if you replace `rand(1:6)` by `ceil(Int, 6rand())` - this is at the cost of minimal loss of precision, see https://juliasnippets.blogspot.com/2017/11/basics-of-generating-random-numbers-in.html.